# display subseconds in time_select in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form to record sports times : I need minutes, seconds and hundredths of second, i.e. 1:31.43 --- I don't need the hour.
In my form I use :

```
<%= f.time_select :perf_time, {:discard_hour => true, :default => {:minute => '00', :second => '00'}, :include_seconds => true} %>
```

This displays 2 select pull-downs, one for minutes and one for seconds.

I have added a separate field for hundredths of second (type Integer):
  `<%= f.number_field :perf_time_cents, :in => 0..999 %>`

Now I'd like to use the method `.change()`in my helper to change add/change the microseconds to perf_time. Here's my code, but it does not do anything.

`before_save :set_perf_time

  def set_perf_time

    self.perf_time.change(usec: (self.perf_time_cents * 10))

  end`

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for milliseconds in `time_select` because a combobox with 1000 possible values would not be user friendly.

You could use instead a separate text field for the number of milliseconds, with the HTML5 type `number`:

```
<%= f.number_field :perf_time_millis, :in => 0..999 %>
```

In the controller, use both the values in the selects and the text input field to get the full time in millis:

```
time_in_millis = params[:perf_time_millis].to_i + 1000 * (params["perf_time(5i)"].to_i * 60 + params["perf_time(6i)"].to_i))
```

Comment: Makes sense. What would be the code for this ? I would need to put it in both `def create` and `def update` ?
Apologies, I started learning Rails 3 days ago...

Comment: @user2721211 Using a `DateTime` is not very easy for this, I would rather save it as a number of milliseconds (`integer` column). I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried in `def create`:

    `def create  
    def set_perf_time  
    perf_time = "#{perf_time}" + "." + "#{perf_time_millis}"  
    end`  


but it does not do anything. I can't find the right syntax.
ps. I set `perf_time_millis` type to integer

Comment: Thanks --- I didn't see your update. However, what should I do with `time_in_millis` ? How do I set `perf_time`to `time_in_millis` ?

Comment: If `perf_time` in an integer column, just use `time_in_millis` to set it and save the object. You seems very lost, take time read the guides, you will learn a lot: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/

Comment: `perf_time`is a time type, which I read supports milliseconds (and can be displayed using %F). My plan was to concatenate `perf_time' and `perf_time_millis'. I understand your solutions is to convert `perf_time`to milliseconds but I prefer to find a shorter route.